# Need help regarding manipulating primeFaces table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to jQuery. I have PrimeFaces dataTable. when it is converted to html. The code looks like this

```
<div id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid" class="ui-datatable ui-widget" style="height:450px;">
    <div id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid_paginatortop" class="ui-paginator ui-paginator-top   ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr" style="">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid:j_idt66" class="ui-state-default"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid_data" class="ui-datatable-data">
                <tr id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid_row_0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even">
                    <td>
                        <div id="question">
                            <label style="color:#0074c7;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold"> Q:</label>
                            <img id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid:0:j_idt69" height="10" width="10" src="/TDAP/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.RC2">
                            <span style="color:#0074c7;font-weight:bold">Customizeddddd development functionality?</span>
                        </div>
                        <img id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid:0:j_idt72" height="10" width="480" src="/TDAP/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.RC2">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div id="answer">
                            <label style="color:#0074c7;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold"> A:</label>
                            <img id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid:0:j_idt75" height="10" width="10" src="/TDAP/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.RC2">
                            This activity executes the configuration, development,     iteration and creation of the Trade Portal elements as defined in the Design Phase. BearingPoint will customize and develop a..
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="horizontalline"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid_row_1" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd">
                    <td>
                        <div id="question">
                            <img id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid:1:j_idt72" height="10" width="480" src="/TDAP/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.RC2">
                             <br>
                             <br>
                        <div id="answer">
                            <div class="horizontalline"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid_row_2" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even">
                <tr id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid_row_3" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd">
                <tr id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid_row_4" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Only first **tr** i shown, that what it looks like in expanded mode. All the remaining are the same. Now i want that when my page loads. Then all the **div** that have **id="answer**. Should not be visible. So when page loads only **div id = "question"** are shown.
Now when you click on question , then only that row **div** with **id=answer** shown, and question hide. And if you again click on the answer, then that row **div** with **id="question** appears, and answer hide.

I tried this

```
(function($){

    $('#FaqGridForm\\:faqGrid tbody').find('tr:has(td)').each(function(){

        var $tr = $(this);
        var $td = $tr.children().find(':has(div #answer)');

        return $td;

    }).hide();


    $('td').click(function(){

        //var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));

        var $clickedItem = $(this);

        var parent = $clickedItem.parent();
        var children = parent.children();
        var index = children.index($clickedItem);

        var $rowClickedItem = $(this);
        var rowParent = $rowClickedItem.parent();
        var parent1 = rowParent.parent();
        var children1 = parent1.children();
        var rowIndex = children1.index(rowParent);

        var rowIndex2 = children1.index(rowParent);

        //var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
        alert('Row: ' + rowIndex + ', Column: ' + colIndex);
    });


})(jQuery); //end of (function($)
```

But my selector is not working. The thing that i am trying to do is , find each row, that has child td with div id=answer, and hide it.

what i am doing wrong. As i told i am new, that's why i am doing wrong :(. Please help.

Thanks

**Edited
--------------------------------------------------------------------------**

This is the Primeface table

```
<div class="newsandupdates1">
    <div class="greyblock">
        <div class="block1" >
            <h:commandLink action="#{faqGrid.toHomePage}" value="Home"/> > FAQ <br></br>
            <br></br> <u><br></br></u>
            <div class="topright"><u> 
                <h:commandLink value="Add FAQ"  action="#{faqGrid.addNewFaq}"
                               rendered="#{faqGrid.showPanel}"/></u><br></br></div></div><br></br>
                <p:dataTable id="faqGrid" var="faqList" value="#{faqGrid.faqCategoryList}" paginator="true" rows="5" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PageLinks} {LastPageLink} " height="400" paginatorPosition="top" style="height:450px;">

                    <p:column >
                        <div id="question">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Q:" style="color:#0074c7;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold"/>
                            <p:spacer width="10" height="10" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{faqList.question}" style="color:#0074c7;font-weight:bold"/>
                        </div>
                        <p:spacer width="480" height="10" />

                        <br></br><br></br>
                        <div id="answer">
                            <h:outputLabel value="A:" style="color:#0074c7;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold"/>
                            <p:spacer width="10" height="10" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{faqList.answer}"/><br></br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="horizontalline"></div>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: first of all, `id` has to be unique across the page/form!

Comment: @Skyrim i edited my code to add Primeface code. You can see there. The id is generated by the Primeface. HHmmm you mean to say the ids should be question1, answer1, question2, answer2,...questionn, answern(n = 1, 2, 3, ....). hhhmmm ok, i try to correct this. Then let you know.

Comment: @Skyrim i Corrected the code. Now the ids are different. The ids with in the each td are now look like this **<span id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid:0:question" style="color:#0074c7;font-weight:bold">Customizeddddd development functionality?</span>**,  **<span id="FaqGridForm:faqGrid:0:answer">This activity executes the configuration, development, iteration and creation of the Trade Portal elements as defined in the Design Phase. BearingPoint will customize and develop a..</span>**  Now indexes are differtnt. Now how can i made selector ?

Comment: I tried this , but i am stuck at a point. I get span array, but then i try to get the valur from array, then nothing happens. Please tell me what i am doing wrong. `var $spanArray = $(this).children('span');` This give me something like this `[span#FaqGridForm:faqGrid:0:question, span#FaqGridForm:faqGrid:0:answer]`. Now i have array that contains two span , but then i try this, nothing happens. It doesn't go inside .each(). `$spanArray.each(function(index){var $span = $(this).get(index); var $span2 = $span;});` . How can i get the span from array, and then get its id and id value.Thanks

Comment: Here i atleast pass trough it, with this `var $spanArray = $(this).children('span'); var length = $spanArray.length; $.each($spanArray, function(index, value){ alert(index + ': ' + value);

      var spanId = value.id;
             
            });`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help...what was wrong?

Comment: Hey it's ok. You did a lot. You told me about the id uniqueness. Please don't be sorry, its ok :). Nothing i just changed the id to class, and then did the things :). I have post my answer. You can see that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
 * When we write jQuery plugins we, of course, must assume that the jQuery library is  loaded. We
 * cannot assume, however, that the $ alias is available. Recall that the $.noConflict() method can
 * relinquish control of this shortcut. To account for this, our plugins should always call jQuery
 * methods using the full jQuery name or internally define $ themselves.
 *
 * Especially in longer plugins, many developers find that the lack of the $ shortcut makes code
 * more difficult to read. To combat this, the shortcut can be locally defined for the scope of the
 * plugin by defining a function and immediately invoking it. This syntax for defining and invoking
 * a function at once, often referred to as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE),
 * looks like the following code snippet:
 *
 * The wrapping function takes a single parameter, to which we pass the global jQuery object. The
 * parameter is named $, so within the function we can use the $ alias with no conflicts.
 *
 * The .ready() method has one more trick up its sleeve to help us in this situation.
 * The callback function we pass to it can take a single parameter: the jQuery object itself. This
 * allows us to effectively rename it without fear of conflicts, as shown in the following code snippet:

   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       // In here, we can use $ like normal!
   });
 *
 * Or, using the shorter syntax we learned in the preceding code:

     jQuery(function($) {
       // Code that uses $.
     });
 */

(function($){

    $('#faqGrid tr td').each(function(){

        var $td = $(this)
        $td.children('div .answer').hide();

//        **
//        *Gives you all children as an object array
//        * 0: div
//        * 1: div
//        * 2: div#question
//        * 3: img#faqGrid:0:j_idt77 /TDAP/fa...=2.2.RC2
//        * 4: br
//        * 5: br
//        * 6: div#answer
//        * 7: div.horizontalline
//        */
//        var tdChildrenArray = $(this).children();
//
//        var divChildrenArray = $(this).children('div');
//
//        var elementStack;
//
//        $.each(divChildrenArray, function(index, value){
//
//           var $div = value;
//
//           if ($div.attr('class')) {
//
//               var $divClass = $div.attr('class');
//
//               if ($divClass == 'answer') {
//
//                  var colNum = $(this).cellIndex;
//                  //$cells = $cells.add($div);
//                  $(value).hide();
//
//               } //end of if ($divId == 'answer')
//
//           } //end of if ($div.id)
//
//        }); //end of  $.each(object, fn)
//
//        //return $(this).pushStack($cells);
//
    }); //end of $('#faqGrid tr td').each(fn)

   /**
    * The .toggle() event method takes two or more arguments, each of which is a function. The first
    * click on the element causes the first function to execute; the second click triggers the
    * second function, and so forth. Once each function has been invoked, the cycle begins again
    * from the first function.
    */
   $('#faqGrid tr td').toggle(function(){

       var $td = $(this)
       $td.children('div .answer').addClass('selected').slideDown('slow', function(){

           $td.children('div .question').slideUp('slow').hide();

      });

   }, function(){

       var $td = $(this)
       $td.children('div .question').addClass('selected').slideDown('slow', function(){

           $td.children('div .answer').slideUp('slow').hide();

        });

    }); //end of $('#faqGrid tr td').toggle

})(jQuery); //end of (function($)
```